# Initialize a List<T> with values that are not null

Tags: c#, list

I'm looking for a way to initialize a variable of type List with a set of values (in C#). Yes, there is object initialization but that requires a new object for each value you want and I would rather avoid it.

Here's a sample:

```
class MyObject
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
List<MyObject> OldNames = new List<MyObject>(10);
List<MyObject> NewNames = new List<MyObject>(5);
```

This is fine and dandy but OldNames contains 10 null references to an object of type MyObject.

Using a list initializer I could do this:

```
List<MyObject> OldNames = new List<MyObject>{
  new MyObject(),
  new MyObject(),
  new MyObject(),
  etc.
```

That's kind of a pain as I have many list variables and various sizes to initialize (for exaample one variable is a list of 26 objects. Yes, I could write a function or maybe extension to do this initialization for me (in a loop where I provide the size) but again that's code I don't necessarily want to write.

I'm hoping there's some kind of lamdba or LINQ expression or something to initialize a list of objects to values instead of nulls.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good idea anyway. Why do you need this?

Comment: The `int` constructor doesn't fill it with null items, it leaves the list empty but with *capacity* for that number of items.

Comment: @SWeko Why is this a bad idea? If you want a list of things that are not null there should be a simple way of initializing the list rather than having to write a loop to do so.

Comment: @Rawling If you want a list of default valued ints you could just intialize an array instead.

Comment: @Bil There are plenty of ways of avoiding writing the loop yourself, but that loop (or something similar) will need to exist somewhere, at some point.  You can't just have the objects magically appear out of nowhere, you need to create N objects *somehow*.

Comment: A list is (more or less) supposed to be a structure that can grow and shrink dynamically. If you have a set number of elements, an array or a dictionary might be a better choice. Also creating lots of objects, that are just empty, rubs me the wrong way. Why not create them when you actually need them?

Comment: @SWeko I see nothing here that would indicate a `Dictionary` is appropriate; there is no mapping relationship.  While a `List` *allows* for dynamic sizing, there's not reason you can't use it even if you have a static size.  There's no real *disadvantage* to that, unless you have some compelling reason to prevent it from being changed.

Comment: @Servy The dictionary came to my mind because of the list of exactly 26 elements. It might be some kind of letter -> object mapping that could use a `Dictionary<char, MyObject>` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys. @Rotem came up with a nice elegant solution using the Enumerable class (a very underused class IMHO). A dictionary might be appropriate but there's no mapping here, just a collection of things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) LINQ  method to specify the number of iterations.

```
List<MyObject> NewNames = Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(i => new MyObject()).ToList();
```

The number `1` here is arbitrary, as the indexer is not used in any way.

Comment: Enumerable.Repeat(5) is ever so slightly better

Comment: Note that this will use the same reference 5 times, which isn't the same as the original code.

Comment: @Jon Yes I just tested that and found out. Thanks, rolling back.

Comment: While this is elegant looking, it doesn't actually create 5 new objects. They're all the same reference like @JonSkeet said so this won't work.

Comment: @Bil `Enumerable.Range` does create unique references, `Repeat` does not.

Comment: It's a nice one-line answer, but it's not very friendly for re-use.

Comment: Exactly what I came here to suggest after Bil informed me about this question.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick musing... you *can* use `Enumerable.Repeat`... just not the way it's been done before. This would work:

```
var query = Enumerable.Repeat<Func<MyObject>>(() => new MyObject(), count)
                      .Select(x => x())
                      .ToList();
```

I'm not suggesting you should *do* this, but it's an interesting alternative to `Enumerable.Range`.

Answer (score 1):

Create yourself a create and initialize function.

```
public List<T> CreateAndInitialize<T>(int size, Func<int, T> init)
{
  var result = new List<T>(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    result.Add(init(i));
  return result;
}
```

Then

```
List<MyObject> newNames = CreateAndInitialize(15, i => return new MyObject());
```

I chose to pass in the index of the object in the init delegate so that you could account for that if needed.

Comment: Note that your lambda expression would be simpler as `i => new MyObject()`

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. result.Count is 0 after the new List<T> call. Had to rewrite it as new List<T>(size) with result.Add(init()) in the body so that works.

Comment: Based on comments, I have updated my answer.  Passing the size to the ctor simply pre-allocates room for elements in the list.  But the size is still 0.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me you are just missing the  () parenthesis after the new declaration.

```
private List<MyObject> ObjectList = new List<MyObject>()
{
        new MyObject() { property1= Value1,  property2 = "Value2"}, 
        new MyObject() { property1= Value1,  property2 = "Value2"} 
};
```